# How to understand and visualize a trained RL agent's policy when the state space is high dimensional?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, policies

What are typical ways to understand and visualize a trained RL agent's policy when the state space is of high dimension (but not images)?

For example, suppose  state and action are denoted by $s=(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_n)$ and $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)$. How do I determine which attribute of the state (e.g. an image pixel of video game) is most responsible for a particular action $a_j$? I would like to have, for each action $a_j, j=1,2,...,k$, a table that ranks the attributes of the observation.

My question may be a little bit vague, but if you have any thoughts on how to improve it please let me know!

Comment: What kind of policy is the agent following? Greedy? If it is random there is no relationship

Comment: I'm not really sure the answer to your question but maybe Figure 4 in this paper might guide you along the right path. [Human level control through deep reinforcement learning](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/MnihEtAlHassibis15NatureControlDeepRL.pdf)